# Fetching JSON Data from URL in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Super new to ExtJS here. I've been trying to fetch data from a local server that provides the data from a database using ExtJS, but to no avail.

The database data can be fetched via Get request at http://localhost:3000/repository of my local machine. I generated a default ExtJS app and have a `PersonalViewStore.js` with the following proxy:

```
proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/repository', 
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        }
    }
```

Note that the JSON database data can be fetched at 'http://localhost:3000/repository'.

Inside of that same `PersonalViewStore.js` file, I've got:

```
fields: [
        'field1', 'field2'
    ],
    autoLoad: true,
```

And inside of the `PersonalView.js` file, I have adapted the columns to be of the same names as the fields that I am fetching from:

```
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'field1',
            dataIndex: 'field1',
            editable: true,
            width: 100,
            cell: {userCls: 'bold'}
        },
        {
            text: 'field2',
            dataIndex: 'field2',
            editable: true,
            width: 150
        }
    ],
```

I've also ensured that the data is properly fetched via POSTMAN at http://localhost:3000/repository. What could go wrong then? Nothing is shown on my ExtJS Grid at http://localhost:1841/#personnelview where the Grid is supposed to be shown, except for the column names 'field1' and 'field2'

Comment: Without seeing a true example and knowing your Ext JS version, we're only making assumptions.  If you could please include a Fiddle, that'd be super.  And just as an initial guess, did you bind your store to your grid?

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the late response (had a long break from work). Attached here is my Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3dr0 (note it is inspired from another post). Notice that I am using data fetched from https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees. My expectation is that when I click on the button 'Get Data Using Store Load', the JSON data from that website should be displayed on the Grid. But that is not the case... I do not believe that I have any issues binding the store to the grid neither.

Comment: No worries!  Your data isn't loading... there's a CORS error.  Pretty sure you can't access any website outside of the Sencha domain... your best bet would be to copy the response on the actual website and put it as a data file on your Fiddle.